# Greedy colouring algorithm on graph in adjacency list representation

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

Suppose you have been given a simple undirected graph and the graph has a max degree of d. You are given d + 1 colors, represented by numbers starting from 0 to d and you want to return a valid placement of colors such that no two adjacent vertices share the same color. And as the title suggests, the graph is given in adjacency list representation. The algorithm should run in O(V+E) time.

I think the correct way to approach this is by using a greedy coloring algorithm. However, this may sound stupid but I am stuck on the part where I try to find the first available color that hasn't been used by its neighbors for each vertex. I don't really know how I can do it so that it runs in O(number of neighbors) time for each vertex that helps to fit under time complexity requirements.

Comment: O(number of colours)=O(number of neighbors). You can just scan a list of colours and the adj list, like using a boolean array if you seen a colour or not. Generally speaking, you direction is correct

Comment: Figured it out but still thanks!